# In the Green Lantern movie, what were the three lessons taught to Hal?

Tags: dc, green-lantern, green-lantern-2011

When Hal Jordan travels to the Green Lantern home world he is taught three lessons by a big ugly dude (what is his name).  What were the three lessons?

Comment: 'Big ugly dude' is Kilowog.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There were about 4 lessons or pieces of advice given to him by Kilowog in the [Green Lantern movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1133985/).

1. Never let your guard down.
2. Your constructs will be only as strong as your will.
3. Gravity makes flying through space very dangerous. Also, in reference to the gravitational pull of the average sun: the bigger you are, the quicker you burn.
4. Your enemy isn't going to play fair.